# D-Link DIR-605L connection dropping every 15 minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

This is a common question but so far I couldn't find an answer. I have this D-Link 605L router and it drops the connection every 15 minutes. I have a macbook running El Capitan and I see that every 15 minutes (more or less) the wifi connection drops. The same happens in my cellphone.

I don't understand much of router so here in some info I see in its admin page.

Hardware Version: B1
Firmware Version: 2.02

Any tips to help me solve it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the connection dropped for a moment or permanently - till you reconnect?

Comment: Yes. For like 15 seconds the wifi is dead, then it comes back

Comment: Have you tried hard resetting the router?

Comment: There is a firmware upgrade V2.06 for that model and B hardware version. you can find it on this page, read upgrade instructions before flashing new firmware...  https://www.mydlink.com/download#

Comment: @Moab Yes, I just did that. Let me test then I return here to tell if it worked or not

Comment: @Moab it solved the issue

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I did as @Moab told, I updated the firmware. I followed this tutorial to do so: [http://support.dlink.ca/FAQView.aspx?f=nvkcNcowupiFvRw0qRTLTQ%3d%3d](http://support.dlink.ca/FAQView.aspx?f=nvkcNcowupiFvRw0qRTLTQ%3D%3D)